# Conversion error in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to execute a query that has a hierarchal relationship between the Customer and Project entities.

I am using a subquery for the Project entity to bring back just the fields that I want instead of using an "Include" that brings back all the fields.

I can't compile it because of the following error (Please use your favorite viewer to enlarge the image).
[image]

If anybody knows how I can solve this, I would appreciate it.

I did the next best thing by executing an anonymous query which produced a valid result set. What I wanted to do at this point is to simply convert the "result" variable into my "Customers" model which has the Project entity as an ICollection (a child of the Customer).

However, I am getting the following error with this approach.
[image]

If anybody can help me out with this, I would also very much appreciate it.

I know what each of the errors mean, but don't quite know how to do the conversion.

### EDIT POSTING CLASSES

### Customer class

```
namespace YeagerTechDB.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]

    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }

        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [EmailAddress]
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        [DataMember]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 99999 or 99999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Website { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string IMAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Project class

```
namespace YeagerTechDB.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Project
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Proj ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short ProjectID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Cust ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        [DataMember]
        public short CategoryID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Priority")]
        [DataMember]
        public short PriorityID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        [DataMember]
        public short StatusID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DataMember]
        public decimal? Quote { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<TimeTracking> TimeTrackings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error clearly suggest what need to be done? You are converting `anonymous` type to `Customer` class.

Comment: Yes, I know, but am having trouble knowing the syntax on actually how to convert them....

Comment: Share code, We can then post updated code, also do share `Customer` and `Project` class defination at least properties

Comment: It appears that `p.Description` is a string which you obviously cannot convert to a `Project` instance. Did you mean `select p` ?

Comment: See edit: EDIT POSTING CLASSES . I appreciate the help very much...

Comment: Alex, for that line, I actually wanted to put out just the columns from the Project class I wanted. Originally, that line was the following: select new {p.Description, p.Quote} which was properly done with the intellisense, but getting that same error on the "select" for that line.

Comment: select `p.Description` makes list of the `string`s and you are trying to assign this collection to list of the `Project`s property (to hashset). Maybe ....`Projects = new HashSet(from p........ select p)`