# Cannot convert anonymous type into my MVC model

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

When running a LINQ query, it runs fine and gets the expected results when I include the "result.Dump()" method. **The anonymous types work fine.**

However, I need to put this anonymous type inside my model and am having the following conversion problem (see image - view image with your favorite viewer).

[image]

Customer is a parent of Projects with the below models. I cannot use typed models due to the following exception in the code:

The entity or complex type 'CodeFirstNamespace.Customer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

```
namespace YeagerTechDB.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]

    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Projects = new HashSet<Project>();
        }

        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(256)]
        [DataMember]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        [EmailAddress]
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Company { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Address1 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Address2 { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataMember]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [StringLength(2)]
        [DataMember]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [StringLength(10)]
        [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 99999 or 99999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Zip { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string HomePhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(12)]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\s*([\(]?)\[?\s*\d{3}\s*\]?[\)]?\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{3}\s*[\-]?[\.]?\s*\d{4}$", ErrorMessage = "Must match 999-999-9999 format")]
        [DataMember]
        public string CellPhone { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Website { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [DataMember]
        public string IMAddress { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<Project> Projects { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace YeagerTechDB.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

    [Serializable, DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public partial class Project
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(false)]
        [Display(Name = "Proj ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short ProjectID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [Editable(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Cust ID")]
        [DataMember]
        public short CustomerID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
        [StringLength(30)]
        [Display(Name = "Project Name")]
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Category")]
        [DataMember]
        public short CategoryID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Priority")]
        [DataMember]
        public short PriorityID { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        [DataMember]
        public short StatusID { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
        [DataMember]
        public decimal? Quote { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [DataMember]
        public string Notes { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Created")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        [Display(Name = "Updated")]
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime? UpdatedDate { get; set; }

        [DataMember]
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public virtual ICollection<TimeTracking> TimeTrackings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conversion error in LINQ query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454685/conversion-error-in-linq-query)